# use of epsilon in proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,g, f_1,f_2,\dots$ be measurable maps from $\Omega \mapsto [0,\infty]$. Then $f_n \uparrow f$ implies $\int f_nd\mu \uparrow \int f d\mu$

I have a problem with the proof presented:
Proof

For each $n,$ we have $f_n \leq f$ and so we have $\int f_n d\mu \leq \int f d\mu$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n  d\mu \leq \int f d\mu.
\end{align*}
For the reverse inequality, it suffices to show that for an arbitrary positive simple $g$ with $g \leq f$ that 
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n d\mu \geq \int g d\mu.
\end{align*}
To this end, let $g$ have the normal representation $g = \sum_{i = 1}^n\alpha_i 1_{A_i}$ for some $\alpha_i \in (0,\infty)$ and and pairwise disjoint sets $A_i$. For any $\epsilon \geq 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N},$ let 
\begin{align*}
    B_n^{\epsilon} =\{f_n \geq (1- \epsilon)g\}
\end{align*}
Since $f_n \uparrow f \geq g$, we have $B_n^{\epsilon} \uparrow \Omega$. Hence, for any $\epsilon >0,$ 
\begin{align*}
    \int f_n d\mu &\geq \int (1-\epsilon)g1_{B_n^{\epsilon}}d\mu\\
    & = \sum_{i = 1}^N (1- \epsilon)\alpha_i\mu(A_i \cap B_i^{\epsilon}) \rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^N(1 - \epsilon)\alpha_i\mu(A_i)\\
    & = (1- \epsilon)\int gd\mu.
\end{align*}

Letting $\epsilon$ go to zero implies the reverse inequality. What is the point of $\epsilon$ here? Why cant we just define $B_n = \{f_n \geq g\}$ and proceed as in the proof to show that $\int f_n d\mu \geq \int g d\mu$?

Comment: How would you define the sets $B^\epsilon_n$?

Comment: define $B_n = \{f_n \geq g\}$ and proceed as in the proof without any of the epsilons

Comment: How would you show that this 'converges' to $\Omega$?

Comment: because $f_n \uparrow f \geq g$

Comment: That won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is simple and $g=f$, and $f_n=(1-1/n)f$, the  set $B_n$ is always empty, so $B_n \uparrow \Omega$ is wrong, but $B_n^{\epsilon}\uparrow \Omega$ holds.